# When using a Hash as a ERB templates, ruby complains about "encoding"

Tags: ruby, erb, ruby-hash

Simply to that

```
require 'erb'
a = "això és una merda <%=rand(1..20)%>"
c = {"id" => "això és una merda <%=rand(1..10)%>"}
```

If you run `ERB.new(a).result`, then all is fine:

```
ERB.new(a).result
=> "això és una merda 3"
```

But with `ERB.new(c).result` ruby complains of `encoding`:

```
ERB.new(c).result
/usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/erb/compiler.rb:315:in `compile': undefined method `encoding' for {"id"=>"això és una merda <%=rand(1..10)%>"}:Hash (NoMethodError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/erb.rb:351:in `initialize'
        from (irb):57:in `new'
        from (irb):57:in `<main>'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/irb-1.4.2/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/bin/irb:25:in `load'
        from /usr/bin/irb:25:in `<main>'
```

My expected result were:

```
{"id" => "això és una merda 3"}
```

I could cast `c` as `string`, but I want as `Hash`.

Comment: You can't render a hash. You need to pass strings to `ERB.new`.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: My expected result were `{"id" => "això és una merda 3"}` for example

Comment: @somenxavier oh, you want to modify your hash values via ERB! That's a totally different use case, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

ERB works solely on strings. If you have a structure *containing* strings like an array of string or a hash with string keys or values, you have to process the strings yourself individually.

To process your hash values, you could use [`transform_values!`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values-21) which passes each value to a block and updates the value with the block's result:

```
require 'erb'

c = {"id" => "això és una merda <%=rand(1..10)%>"}

c.transform_values! { |str| ERB.new(str).result }

c #=> {"id"=>"això és una merda 7"}
```

(there's also a non-`!` variant which returns a new hash without modifying the receiver)

Comment: I can evaluate ERB templates with `.to_s` but I cannot apply `.to_s` and `to_hash` with text with `\frac{1}{2}`

Comment: @somenxavier I've updated the answer. What do you mean by `\frac{1}{2}`?

Comment: It's a LaTeX command to display a fraction with numerator equals to 1 and denominator equals to 2

Comment: I know, but it appears nowhere in your question.